# How can I inspect an element with vimperator/pentadactyl?

Tags: firefox, vimperator, pentadactyl, firefox-developer-tools

I'd like to be able to inspect an element (i.e. a link) with the built-in Firefox inspection tool, similar to right-clicking on an element and selecting "Inspect Element," only I'd like to be able to do it with Vimperator/Pentadactyl, with the keyboard. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I didn't see it in the doc. You could suggest an enhancement here: https://code.google.com/p/vimperator-labs/issues/list

Answer (score 2):

I was actually looking for this feature in Pentadactyl a few days ago, but like Ehvince, I couldn't find it in the documentation. I'm sure a plugin can be written for it, but I tried to find a workaround for now.

The closest I could get was to use extended hint mode to open the context (right click) menu somewhere on the page, and choose "Inspect element" from there. By default, it's at `;c` and shows the default hints (for links, text areas, and so on).

You can set the extended hint tags to your desired CSS selectors with the `eht` (or `extendedhinttags`) option, just like with `hinttags`. To add hint tag selectors specifically for the context menu mode, you would do:

`:set eht+=[c]:a,div,p,span`

That will look kind of messy as it hints at every `div` on the page—you may want to be more specific with your selectors to suit your needs—but it works.

It would be awesome to write a developer plugin for Pentadactyl with features such as this one. One day, some day.

**More information**

[Pentadactyl Help - ‘extendedhinttags’ option](http://5digits.org/help/pentadactyl/options.xhtml#%27extendedhinttags%27)
[Pentadactyl Help - Hints (and extended hints)](http://5digits.org/help/pentadactyl/hints.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox (Version 34 at least, not sure about earlier verisons), has a built in option to show the Inspector with Ctrl-Shift-c.